# Using async and future is throwing exception on linux (gcc 4.8.4)

Tags: multithreading, c++11, g++

I have a simple piece of code that throws an exception when it shouldn't.
All the appropriate headers were included and the program builds without errors. Code below.  The exception occurs when executing result1.get();
Could some please tell me what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks in advance for any help.

```
int func1 ()
{
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    future<int> result1(async(func1));
    int result = result1.get();
    return 0;
}
```

The result of running the program gives me this:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error'
what():  Unknown error -1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `-pthread` to the compiler flags. Not sure about the details, but for somewhat reason gcc 4.8 gives the `Unknown error -1` if this has been left out (however, at least IMHO, it should either warn that you have not enabled threading or give some linking error instead of compiling and throwing in runtime).

Comment: Tried including the -pthread flag but that didn't resolve the problem.  I'm wondering if there's a bug in gcc 4.8.4.

Comment: @Smithy ok, the tutorial page link is broken, seems that the project cannot be shared. The command line in the example was `g++ -std=c++11 -pthread -o main *.cpp` and that seemed to work fine. It of course could be that gcc 4.8.4 introduced a bug but I highly doubt that.

Comment: @Smithy what linux flavor/version are you using? Maybe https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gcc-defaults/+bug/1228201 is relevant?

Comment: Thanks for your input.  I tried compiling from the shell and all worked but the -pthread is definitely required.  However I'm using Eclipse and adding the flag makes no difference, the exception is still raised.

Comment: Using Ubuntu 14.04, gcc 4.8.4; Eclipse Kepler Service Release 2

Comment: @Smithy well at least we got that sorted out. I have an idea, maybe eclipse breaks the building into compilation and linking steps and then I assume you would also need to add `-lpthread` to the linker flags. In case of a single `gcc` call the `-pthead` applies to both compilation and linking. In case of eclipse it could be that it only applies to compilation (however then again, I would expect ld to throw errors, but I am not that good with gcc).

Comment: Well guess what?  Adding the -lpthread did the trick.  Thanks again for your help.  Now I can start work on my project.  FYI: I tried the same code on Jetbrains Clion for C++ and using only the compilation flag -pthread in the compiler worked perfectly without adding the -lpthread to the linker.

Comment: @Smithy, well as I said, it depends on if the compilation/linking stages are done in one step or split:) So will you accept the answer?